# Get Access Data within Excel "contains no visible table"

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

I would like to connect my Excel file to an Access database. Exporting directly from Access to Excel is not an option because it is too tedious (I just wanna click refresh and get the updated Access data). In Excel, when I try to connect it by 'Data' 'From Access", it gives me an error saying 'This data source contains no visible tables'.

The import works with a local Access table, but the one I am working with is a linked table. In Access, I also tried to create a query from the linked table, but Excel also cannot find this one. Is there a quick solution to this problem? (All of the tables are unhidden, btw)

Please keep in mind that I cannot download Excel Power Query at the moment (admin rights etc). I added this pic to show you the icons of the Access database:

[image: I added this pic to show you the icons of the Access database]

Thanks!

Comment: If you try to make a normal, non-linked table in Access, would it be visible?

Comment: Yes, it would be visible...

Comment: so i really dont know whats going on there

Comment: Why not just use the actual source database? Excel does not like linked tables or functions in querydefs.

Comment: Does the import work on a local table in the same database as the linked table?